# Fork and Pull Method Not Working on GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am new to `git` and GitHub (where my username is `myuser`). I am trying to submit my first ever pull request and am running into some issues.

1. I forked a repo of a project that I need to patch, called `someuser/somerepo`. Hence, I now have a `myuser/somerepo` repo.
2. I cloned my fork locally and created a branch (`mybranch`).
3. I made various changes to `mybranch`.
4. I ran `git commit -a -m "Closes someuser/somerepo/#10"`
5. Then I ran `git push`, where I was asked to authenticate.

After the successful `git push`, I see:

- In `mysuer/somerepo` on GitHub, I see all the changes that I made there.
- In `someuser/somerepo` on GitHub, I see a message under Issue #10 stating `myuser referenced this issue from a commit in myuser/somerepo 2 hours ago`

So, off the cuff, it seemms like I've actually managed to do everything correctly so far. So I Googled "*GitHub how to pull request*" and I found this [GitHub wiki article](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/).

According to that article I need to go into GitHub, and from "the repository from which I'd like to propose changes", I need to choose the `mybranch` option from the *Branches* menu.

However, I do not see `mybranch`, I only see the branches that existed in the repo that I forked. This tells me I missed something.

So I have to ask (because they are all similarly related):

1. **Have I missed anything or overlooked anything?** I am not a 'member' of the `somerepo` repo, I have never contacted any of its maintainers; I guess I'm wondering if I don't even have permission to do a pull request. **In which case my question would be: how does the GitHub repo authorization model work?** (what users can do what to a repo)?
2. What decides whether one "*forks and pulls*" or goes with a "shared repo"? Do pull requests occur in both situations?

Ultimately: **What's my next step here, and how do I fix this so I can continue putting in my pull request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you haven't pushed your branch up to your fork repository, try doing:

```
git push -u origin mybranch
```

Here I'm assuming your remote is `origin` (as by default). If not, use your remote's name instead of `origin`.

EDIT:

I think there are some conditions (non fast-forward changes) in which your changes in a local branch will be pushed to the "default" remote branch (usually `master`) when you don't specify the destination branch (i.e. by doing `git push`), but of course this may be not your case at all :)

If you want to make sure your changes are in `mybranch`, try the url

`https://github.com/[user-name]/[repo-name]/tree/mybranch`

It should show you your uploaded branch.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: Thanks @KeillRandor (+1) - but I'm pretty sure I did. Otherwise, how could I see my changes showing upn **on GitHub** under `myuser/myrepo`?

Answer (score 1):

You are super close. You actually want to go to your fork, click pull requests on the right, and click new to start the process

Comment: Thanks @DVG (+1) - if you get a moment, can you read KeiillRandor's answer and my follow up comment? I think KeillRandor is mistaken, but I'm so new to this, I can't make heads or tails of it. Thanks again!